# How to set SQL Server procedure variables to inputted data from C# ASP.NET MVC program?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

When using this code, I get an error

> Procedure or function 'Registration' expects parameter '@qUsername', which was not supplied

Can someone please tell me how to fix this? This is my controller code and the SQL query for registration

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "UserID,Username,FirstName,LastName,Email,Password,Number,IsAdmin,Salt")] UsersTable usersTable)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Int32 rowsAffected;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(@"xxx");

            cmd.CommandText = "dbo.Registration";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

            sqlConnection1.Open();

            rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            sqlConnection1.Close();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(usersTable);
}
```

Procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Registration
    @qUsername NVARCHAR(50),
    @qPassword NVARCHAR(50),
    @qFirstName NVARCHAR(40),
    @qLastName NVARCHAR(40),
    @errorResponse NVARCHAR(250) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID()

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO dbo.UsersTable (UserID, Password, Salt, FirstName, LastName)
        VALUES (@qUsername, HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @qPassword + CAST(@salt AS NVARCHAR(36))), @salt, @qFirstName, @qLastName)

        SET @errorResponse = 'Success'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @errorResponse = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Are you using an SP to create your user, or are you using an ORM to make an insert directly into the table? Because I see both.

Comment: Yes - why are you doing this twice? Once you get your proc working it's going to insert the same record twice in two different ways

Comment: @EzLo Sorry I'm relatively new to the whole MVC C# thing, especially with the fact that I've not really done much database work either, could you please explain what it is I've done wrong?

Comment: ORMs are libraries that allow you to manipulate rows from your database as if they were objects. You can map you database table with a class (like your UsersTables), then just instantiate it, fill their fields and save it on database through a `SaveChanges()` method. This will make the ORM insert your object as row behind curtains. On the other hand if you use an SP and supply the parameters, you don't need to map your class against a table and you can have additional logic on the SQL side.

Comment: In your case, you are executing an SP which will insert your row, but you are also executing the `SaveChanges()` with the ORM, which will also try to insert the fields of the `UsersTables` object that you added.

Comment: @EzLo Ohh, I understand now, thank you for the explanation, I just saw the code, I forgot I'd left it in when I posted it, whoops, but it's gone in my actual code now. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **define and set** the parameters for the stored procedure before your call it from your C# code - like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.Registration";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

// define and set parameters!
cmd.Parameters.Add("@qUsername", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = .....;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@qPassword", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = .....;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@qFirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = .....;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@qLastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = .....;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@errorResponse", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

sqlConnection1.Open();
rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise I needed to define and set the parameters in the controller as well as in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qUsername", "xxxxx");
```

For all parameters before calling:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: *Don't* use `AddWithValue`. [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: thanks      
command.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = "Smith";